# Serverless card payment processor integration options

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, payment-gateway, braintree

I m currently developing an app for a local company that needs to integrate card payments for enabling customers to buy some sort of physical products.

Are there any options for a "serverless" card payment integration?

Unfortunately I cant use Stripe + Firebase because Stripe is not available for my country. (Romania)

Has anyone implemented a card payment solution using Braintree payments and Firebase?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase `functions-samples` repo contains examples of processing payments with [Stripe](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe) and with [Paypal](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/paypal). If you look at the code for these, you'll see that the Firebase aspects of them are fairly similar, and the main differences are in the calls to the Paypal/Stripe API.

If you need to support another payment provider, you will have to make your own implementation of this approach, typically using these examples as a template. I also recommend checking out the video explaining this flow: [Go serverless: manage payments in your apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE).

Comment: You're welcome Paul. Whoever downvoted, can you explain why please?

Comment: Somebody who voted to close likely downvoted - with the rationale that if a question is off-topic, answering it encourages more off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks Wai, that makes sense. It's one of those guidelines I disagree with, but at least it would explain. :)